# Using Powershell to download and run exe file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to download Malwarebytes Anti-Rootkit Beta but my PowerShell script throws the error below. How do I fix this?

My Script:

```
$url = "https://data-cdn.mbamupdates.com/web/mbar-1.10.3.1001.exe"
$outpath = "$PSScriptRoot/mbar-1.10.3.1001.exe"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $outpath)

$args = @("Comma","Separated","Arguments")
Start-Process -Filepath "$PSScriptRoot/mbar-1.10.3.1001.exe" -ArgumentList $args
```

The Error:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:8 char:1
+ Start-Process -Filepath "$PSScriptRoot/mbar-1.10.3.1001.exe" -Argumen ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: Two asides: For a more PowerShell-idiomatic download solution, try `Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile $outPath $url`. Unless the downloaded file is a console application that you deliberately want to run _asynchronously_, in a _separate window_, invoke it _directly_, as `& $outPath ...`

Comment: Also, don't use `$args` as a self-defined variable name, as it is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#args) in PowerShell.